# My Scheduled Background Task Does Not Seem to Run

Tags: ios, task, schedule, background-task

I am trying to setup this background task for my app that runs repeatedly every 5 minutes. The task get's scheduled but the task itself never runs. I also never see the task registered.
App Delegate:

```
import UIKit
import BackgroundTasks
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.backgroundTaskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleBackgroundTask(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
      
        }

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Bold", size: 18)! ], for: .normal)
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    
       

        func handleBackgroundTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
            task.expirationHandler = {
                // Handle expiration if necessary
                print("task expired")
            }
            print("starting task")
            // Perform the background task
            BackgroundTaskManager.performBackgroundTask { result in
                task.setTaskCompleted(success: result == .newData)
                
                scheduleBackgroundTask()

            }
        }
        
        // Other AppDelegate methods...
    }
  
func scheduleBackgroundTask() {
    print("Task Scheduled")
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.backgroundTaskIdentifier)
    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10) // 5 minutes
    
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to schedule background task: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I also have the `scheduleBackgroundTask()` function set to run in the home screen and I have set it to run every 10 seconds for testing purposes.

Comment: The place where you `print("task registered")` isn't actually where the task is registered, it's where the task runs. You can't control specifically when a background task is executed, iOS decides that. The code you have now simply guarantees that it won't run within the next 5 minutes after it's scheduled, but when it actually executes is undefined (usually several hours later, determined by the user's usage patterns to ensure your task doesn't take up additional resources while they're using their device)

Comment: Got it Thank You, yeah looks like it just worked for me. I didn't know it wasn't guaranteed it would run in the time interval specified.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have a background task be guaranteed to execute using a different method or framework?

Comment: There is not one natively, no. People have sorta hacked around this before with silent push notifications, but that's an abuse of the system that Apple generally doesn't appreciate. Typically you'd send one of those only when there's content that's definitely changed server-side and needs to be refreshed

Comment: " hacked around this before with silent push notifications, but that's an abuse of the system that Apple generally doesn't appreciate". That's not a hack at all, and not only do Apple not appreciate it, they document it as a viable approach. However the issue with silent pushes is that they aren't delivered at all if the app has been terminated, or they can be delayed by hours or also not delivered if the app has now battery levels, plus a few other similar limitations.